# How to pass the SAFE MODE Restriction in PHP?

Tags: php, linux

> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]:
>   SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The
>   script whose uid is 1191 is not
>   allowed to access
>   /home/yasimtr1/domains/yasisyazilim.com.tr/public_html/kamuoyutv/data/videos/archive/2011/2/26
>   owned by uid 101 in
>   /home/yasimtr1/domains/yasisyazilim.com.tr/public_html/kamuoyutv/index/phplibrary/action.php
>   on line 446

the folders have the permission 0777.

How can I fix this bug?

If you need more information to solve, ask me.

Comment: Why is your script running as a different user than the user who owns the data?

Comment: although the folder 26 is created by the same script it gives this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is on some webhosting provider, you won't have direct access to the php.ini file. However, there are several methods that you can try to enable it. Most providers don't allow you to enable it though, for security reasons.

If your host has an online control panel, check to see if they have an option to turn off Safe Mode. Although most don't, it may be worth a try.

Some providers also allow you to turn it off with a .htaccess file. If so, add the following line to your htaccess file:

```
php_flag safe_mode off
```

If those two options fail, you have one final option: Try asking your host provider. They might surprise you and turn it off for you.

Comment: I've changed the .htaccess file. There is only one line in it which you gave me. However it doesn't work. Should I add extra codes or lines to it?

Comment: No, that line alone should do the trick, if overrides were enabled. However, it doesn't look like they are enabled =/ So I suppose you have to talk to your host

Answer (score 3):

in php.ini:

```
safe_mode = Off
open_basedir =
```

Comment: I don't have access to "PHP.ini". This is a hosting