# Safe Mode Restriction in Effect with Safe Mode Off

Tags: php, linux, permissions, php-safe-mode

I have a problem with the "Safe Mode". In my php.ini is off so i cant undestand the error:

> PHP Warning:  fopen(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script
>   whose uid is 10003 is not allowed to access /tmp/51bef5d81180e owned
>   by uid 0 in ......

I think it could be a permissions problem, but im not sure. I gave permissions to 10003 with:

```
sudo chown -R 10003 /tmp
```

but stills the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious, did you try to read a safe mode description on the manual page?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125651/how-to-pass-the-safe-mode-restriction-in-php

Comment: Yes, Your Common Sense, i did it. Thanks. Any idea?